# Change userIp parameter of the bing maps request

Tags: maps, bing-maps, bing

Im using the bing maps REST services from server side code. I want to set the userIp parameter to 127.0.0.1.

Can you guys provide the steps how to set the value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add `&userIp=127.0.0.1` to your REST URL